# Combinations of values using map in C++

Tags: c++, string, loops, dictionary, permutation

So the user will enter 3 digits and (without duplicates) all the possible combinations should be printed from the map. I'm having trouble with doing the correct loops to print those combinations without having to do each and every case for the number that's entered. I'll have to rewrite the program later to account for any amount of digits entered, so I'm wondering what I should do with my loop in the `PrintAllString` function to print the combinations of the individual character values in the string part of the map? Also, for the case of 0, 1, or 9 entered where the number of characters in the string map isn't the same, the combinations will have to account for that, and I'm having trouble implementing those conditions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef map<int, string> phonemap;
void createPhoneMap(phonemap &mapIn);//create the map for phone Keyboard
void PrintAllString(string phonenum, phonemap mapIn); //print out all the combinations
void PrintMap(phonemap mapIn); //print out the data in  mapIn
phonemap MyMap; //global variable 
string phonenum;//global string contains user input phone number

int main()
{
    cout << "Please input the phone number (3 digits,no space): ";
    cin >> phonenum;
    cout << endl;

    createPhoneMap(MyMap); //MyMap is same as mapIn
    PrintMap(MyMap);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Print all combinations:" << endl << endl;
    PrintAllString(phonenum, MyMap);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void createPhoneMap(phonemap &mapIn)
{
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(0, "*"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(1, "#"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(2, "ABC"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(3, "DEF"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(4, "GHI"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(5, "JKL"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(6, "MNO"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(7, "PQR"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(8, "STU"));
    mapIn.insert(pair<int, string>(9, "VWXYZ"));

    return;
}

void PrintMap(phonemap mapIn)
{
    for (map<int, string> ::iterator it = mapIn.begin(); it != mapIn.end(); it++)
        cout << "<" << it->first << ", " << it->second << ">" << endl;

    return;
}

void PrintAllString(string phonenum, phonemap mapIn)
{
    int num1 = phonenum[0] - '0';
    int num2 = phonenum[1] - '0';
    int num3 = phonenum[2] - '0';

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        auto it1 = mapIn.find(num1);
        auto it2 = mapIn.find(num2);
        auto it3 = mapIn.find(num3);

        //So the map values with only one character in the string won't give an error
        if (num1 == 0 || num1 == 1 || num2 == 0 || num2 == 1 || num3 == 0 || num3 == 1)
        {
            num1 = 0;
            num2 = 0;
            num3 = 0;
        }

        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i] << it3->second[i] << endl;
        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i] << it3->second[i + 1] << endl;
        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i] << it3->second[i + 2] << endl;
        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i + 1] << it3->second[i] << endl;
        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i + 1] << it3->second[i + 1] << endl;
        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i + 1] << it3->second[i + 2] << endl;
        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i + 2] << it3->second[i] << endl;
        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i + 2] << it3->second[i + 1] << endl;
        cout << it1->second[i] << it2->second[i + 2] << it3->second[i + 2] << endl;

        cout << endl;
    }

    return;
}
```

If a three digit number is entered, (023 for example) the output should be:

> *AD
>   *AE
>   *AF
>   *BD
>   *BE
>   *BF
>   *CD
>   *CE
>   *CF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may help, it use a `vector` `it` which contains all values of iterators if you do the loops manually:

```
// increment the iterator by one, return false when reset all values to 0.
bool increase(const std::vector<std::string>& v, std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = it.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] == v[index].size()) {
            it[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void do_job(const std::vector<std::string>& v, std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = v.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        std::cout << v[i][it[i]];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void iterate(const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> it(v.size(), 0);

    do {
        do_job(v, it);
    } while (increase(v, it));
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/vU4jL5)

Comment: Okay I can follow code pretty well, except it's hard to see what your program is actually doing with no comments or anything of what it accomplishes. Regardless, I'm not using vectors at all, your method wouldn't help because it's dependent on them.

Comment: @T-Bird: answer edited to match your requirement: ([Live example](https://ideone.com/vU4jL5))

Comment: I implemented it and was able to use this method with any amount of numbers entered after some modification, I took out one of the for loops that you used as well but you definitely gave me the code I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//remove and return first character of s...
char chomp(string & s) {
  if (s.length()==0) return 0;
  char res = s.at(0);
  s.erase(0,1);
  return res;
}

//gradually eats nums from the front and builds sofar...
list<string> combos(Phonemap map, list<string> sofar, string nums) {
  if (nums.length()==0) 
    return sofar;
  list<string> next;
  char cc, c = chomp(nums);
  string fm = map[c-'0']; //e.g. ABC
  //make all combinations of something in sofar 
  // followed by something in the "ABC"-like string
  while (cc = chomp(fm))
    for (list<string>::iterator i = sofar.begin(); i!=sofar.end(); i++)
      next.push_back( (*i) + string( 1,cc) );
  //recurse to eat the rest of nums..
  return combos(map, next, nums);
}


int main()  {
  Phonemap pm;
  createPhoneMap(pm);
  string test("023");
  list<string> e;
  e.push_back("");
  list<string> co = combos(pm, e, test) ;
  for (list<string>::iterator i = co.begin(); i!=co.end(); i++)
    cout << *i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive implementation, it relies on all `build` has the same length. That `phonenum` has been checked before hand and thus only consist of digits. That `phonenum` has a finite length.

```
void Recursive(const char *phonenum, const phonemap& mapIn, char *build, int len) {
    if (!(*phonenum)) {
        printf("%s\n", build);
        return;
    }
    int ciffer = (*phonenum)-'0'; // you promised me a phone number all digits
    ++phonenum; // next digit
    const std::string& cmap = mapIn[ciffer];
    for (auto it = cmap.cbegin(); it < cmap.cend(); ++it) {
        build[len] = *it;
        Recursive(phonenum, mapIn, build, len+1);
    }
}

constexpr int MaxPhoneNumberLength = 128; // replace with real value or higher safe value
void PrintAllString(const std::string phonenum, const phonemap& mapIn) {
    char build[MaxPhoneNumberLength+1] {0}; // longest possible phone number
    assert(phonenum.length()<=MaxPhoneNumberLength);

    Recursive(phonenum.c_str(), mapIn, build, 0);

    return;
}

typedef std::array<std::string, 10> phonemap;
const phonemap MyMap {
    "*",
    "#",
    "ABC",
    "DEF",
    "GHI",
    "JKL",
    "MNO",
    "PQR",
    "STU",
    "VWXYZ"
};
```

Comment: What compiler are you using here?

Comment: @AdrianMay, GCC 4.9.1 I think. C++11.

Comment: permissive? At "mapIn[ciffer]" I'm getting x.cpp:34:43: error: passing ‘const phonemap {aka const std::map<int, std::basic_string<char> >}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = std::basic_string<char>; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::basic_string<char> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::basic_string<char>; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: @AdrianMay, oops, I made a small change to the layout of the data, using 'std::array<std::string, 10>' instead of map.

Comment: @AdrianMay, its the 'const' in the parameters that seems to be the problem, as usage of map[] can't be 'const'.